# Global Variables in Micro-Web Framework

Tags: python-2.7, web, bottle

I am building a small micro-web application using bottle. First step is that the user inputs an ID into a form in order to retrieve a record. Once the ID has been verified as part of the SQLite database further steps will be taken, they can modify records, add data to another .db with the same PRIMARY KEY and so on and so forth.

My question is, within the session how do I preserve the ID once verified and pass it around the various functions. Should it be a global created inside the function that verifies the user input? I am wary of globals, just because so much junk is talked about them. Also, I am nervous that if not very well managed the user could restart the session enter new data but the global ID variable might not have been properly disposed of etc....

What is the correct way to approach this?

Im not sure it helps, but here is the code I am using so far....

```
import bottle as bt
import webbrowser as wb
import re, sqlite3

@bt.route('/welcome', method = 'GET')
def welcome():
    return """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Bottle Micro-Web Test Application</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <h1>Welcome to the Factory Database Test Micro-Web Application</h1>
            <div/>
            <div style="text-align:left;">
                <h2>To call up a record please enter a valid UID in the box below:<h2>
            <div/>
            <form action="/welcome/result" method="post">
                UID: <input type="text" name="UID"><br/>
                <input value="Get Records" type="submit">
            </form>
            <body>
    <html>
    """

@bt.route('/welcome/result', method = 'POST')
def report_welcome():
    uid = bt.request.forms.get('UID')
    return check_user_input(uid)

def check_user_input(uid):
    uid_pattern = re.compile("[Mm]\d\d\d")
    if not uid_pattern.match(uid):
        return """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Bottle Micro-Web Test Application</title>
        </head>
            <body>
                <font size="6" color="red">That was an invalid UID!</font>
                <p> A valid UID has the form M001</p>
                <form action="http://localhost:8080/welcome">
                <input type="submit" value="Back">
                </form>
            <body>
        <html>
        """
    else:
        uid = uid.upper()
        conn = sqlite3.connect('factories.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        result = tuple(c.execute("SELECT uid FROM factories WHERE uid = ?", (uid,)))
        if result:
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM factories WHERE uid = ?", (uid,))
            record = c.fetchone()
            conn.close()
            return bt.template("{{record}}", record = str(record))
        else:
            return """
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Bottle Micro-Web Test Application</title>
            </head>
                <body>
                    <font size="6" color="red">That UID does not exist in the database</font>
                    <form action="http://localhost:8080/welcome">
                    <input type="submit" value="Back">
                    </form>
                <body>
            <html>
            """

wb.open('http://localhost:8080/welcome')
bt.run(host = 'localhost', port = 8080, debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the id for a single request then passing around the local variable as you seem to be doing is better than using globals.

If you want to preserve the id across requests you can save the value in cookies(if safety of id is not a concern) and access it then easily. The cookie's are saved on the user's computer and are accessible only during the request. For more on using cookies in bottle refer bottle's documentation(it is explained in the tutorial).

Also: instead of embedding the html in your code use templates! It will make your code neater.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Yes I am using templates. In the end I am actually passing the id around in the url, it seems to work very well. I am still battling the globals issue though because I have a form spread over 5 pages (its very long) and each page is validated in turn. I then have to store the data in a global dictionary, which I am not comfortable with. Can't see any other way to do it though... Thanks for your suggestions.